# Quarkus TLS Exception: DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) An exceptionCaught() event was fired

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, quarkus

On a simple CRUD application when SSL was configured on Quarkus (basic configurations) the logs show this warning (this warming repeats every second)

**The Exception**

```
2020-08-26 12:49:53,067 DEBUG [io.net.han.ssl.SslHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) [id: 0x89c3e82b, L:/10.221.49.135:8443 - R:/10.221.82.1:45028] HANDSHAKEN: protocol:TLSv1.2 cipher suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2020-08-26 12:49:53,155 WARN  [io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**The used configurations are**

```
quarkus.http.ssl-port=8443
quarkus.http.insecure-requests=redirect
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=META-INF/keystore.jks
```

The application is deployed on Openshift.

If I debug, I can see that my application on the POD is trying to connect some IP

```
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/XX.XX.72.42:8443 remote=/XX.XX.84.1:49516]

Where XX.XX.72.42 is the POD IP

Where XX.XX.84.1 no idea
```

Besides the log, all seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

So this can be normal if the connection has been closed by the client (`XX.XX.84.1` being the IP address of the client connecting to your application).

It might not be a real issue.

Agree the warn message is not very nice though. Maybe open an issue in our tracker so that someone can see if we can improve or if it should stay like this.